# How do i pass the variable value in object in node js

Tags: node.js, rest

I want pass the encrypted password into the object. So when API called password will be in the encrypted form.

```
app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {

   const user = {
        id: 1,
        username: "Vinit",
        password: "12345" //Here I want to pass the encrypted password
    }

    jwt.sign({user: user}, 'secretkey', (err, token) => {
        res.json({
            token: token
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you mean like passing `req.body.password`?

Comment: yes @David but in the encrypted format.

Comment: hash it with bcrypt libary.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Answer (score 1):

If not already implemented you need to use third party library like [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs). Then you can generate hashed password like this

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash("NON_HASHED_PASSWORD", salt, function(err, hash) {
        console.log(hash) //<- Hashed password
    });
});
```

Remember this process is `async` in nature.

Read more about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs#usage---async)

Comment: Please: [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) and [encrypting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) are different things.

Answer (score 1):

Try [passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) - It has lots of strategies including `jwt`, `google auth`, `facebook`.. etc